# Can't write to lockfile while frozen Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, lockfile

Hello I'm trying to run the following commands to prep my Rails app for production:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby

bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

Then I get this error:

```
Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
```

What is going on here? What is the lockfile for? What does it mean to be frozen?

Answer (score 8):

Running the following command allowed me to write to my lock file

```
bundle config unset deployment
```

Comment: Once this is done, the add-platform works, but do I need to set deployment again?

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this in development:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby

bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

and then commit, push and pull into production.  No need to unfreeze your bundle and no need to get your development and production repositories out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are in production and you dont want any changes to you Gemfile.lock file in deployment, so you freeze it, to unfreeze it run:

```
bundle config unset frozen
```